# Pointwise existence of Radon-Nikodým derivative sufficient for absolute continuity?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a finite, nonatomic, signed Radon measure on $([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1]))$. For all $x \in ]0,1[$ the limit
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} {\frac{\mu(]x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon[)}{2\varepsilon}}$$
exists. Does this imply that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$?

If $\mu$ was a positive measure, this would follow from a version of Besicovitch's Differentiation Theorem, see Theorem 2.22 in *Functions of Bounded Variation and Free Discontinuity Problems* by Ambrosio, Fusco, Pallara.
In the general case I could imagine that two positive, singular continuous measures could be used to give a counterexample, but I haven't been able to construct them.

Edit: I was thinking about a middle-half Cantor probability distribution as positive part and as negative part a probability measure constructed in the following way: At step $n$ of the construction of the Cantor set we have $2^n$ intervals of length $4^{-n}$ left; consider the two intervals next to each of these intervals, also of length $4^{-n}$ and uniformly distribute weight on them in order to get a probability measure. The weak*-limit of those measures shall constitute the negative part. - I'm rather convinced that the resulting signed measure has pointwise Radon-Nikodým derivative 0, but I fear that in the end it's the zero measure, so both constructions (of positive and negative part) give the same measure.

Edit no. 2: It is indeed the zero measure. :(

Comment: What about considering the decomposition of positive measures, $\mu=\mu_+ - \mu_-$?

Comment: That's what I had in mind when I was talking about the two positive singular continuous measures. But it doesn't seem to help for a proof of absolute continuity. Negative part and positive part could both have infinite density at some points, even at points of a Lebesgue-nullset.

Comment: When $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\mu(]x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon[)}{2\epsilon}$ is integrable or even continuous, do you have any conclusion?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @richard. After I read your comment, I had another look at my sources and stumbled upon the de la Vallée Poussin theorem, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had another look at A. Bruckner's »Differentiation of Integrals« (The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 78, No. 9, Part 2: Differentiation of Integrals (Nov., 1971), pp. i-iii+1-51) and found a mention of the *de la Vallée Poussin decomposition theorem*, which is a refinement of Lebesgue's decomposition theorem. The expository paper cites Saks' »Theory of the Integral«, where you can find the general theorem as Theorem (15.7) on page 155. A modern treatment can be found as Theorem 8.21 in »Real Analysis« by A. Bruckner, J. Bruckner and Thompson ([free download here](http://www.classicalrealanalysis.info/com/FREE-PDF-DOWNLOADS.php)). The problem with both sources is that they prove the theorem only for differentiation with respect to net structures, which is not applicable here.

But I think you can modify their approach to make it work here where the differentiation base consists of balls. I will sketch how:

The following lemma corresponds to the growth lemma, Lemma 8.20 in »Real Analysis«:

> **Lemma:** Let $\nu$ be a (signed) finite Radon measure on a cube $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then:
>
> 1. If $A \subseteq X$ is a Borel set, $q \in \mathbb{R}$, and $\overline{D} \nu(x) := \limsup \limits_{r \downarrow 0} {\frac{\nu(\overline{B}_r(x))}{\lambda(\overline{B}_r(x))}} \geq q$ for all $x \in A$, then $\nu(A) \geq q \lambda (A)$.
> 2. If $B \subseteq X$ is a Borel set, $\lambda(B)=0$, and $\nu$ does not have an infinite derivative at any point of $B$, then $\nu(B) = 0$.

**Proof**: Assume $q=0$; the general case can then be proved by considering $\tilde{\nu} := \nu - q\lambda$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $|\nu|$ is outer regular, there exists an open set $G \supseteq A$ such that $\lambda(G) < \infty$ and $|\nu|(E) < \varepsilon$ for every Borel set $E \subseteq G \setminus A$. Consider
$$\mathcal{F} := \{\overline{B}_r(x) \: | \: x \in A,\, \overline{B}_r(x) \subseteq G,\, \nu(\overline{B}_r(x)) > -\varepsilon\, \lambda(\overline{B}_r(x))\}.$$
By the Vitali-Besicovitch covering theorem (Theorem 2.19 in »Functions of Bounded Variation and Free Discontinuity Problems«) there exists a countable disjoint subfamily $\mathcal{F}' \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ such that $|\nu|\left(A \setminus \bigcup \mathcal{F}'\right) = 0$. Now $\bigcup \mathcal{F}' \subseteq G$ and
$$\left|\nu \left(G \setminus \bigcup \mathcal{F}'\right)\right| \leq |\nu| \left(A \setminus \bigcup \mathcal{F}'\right) + |\nu| \left(G \setminus \left(A \cup \bigcup \mathcal{F}'\right)\right) < 0 + \varepsilon = \varepsilon.$$
Now the rest of the proof of Lemma 8.20 goes through without changing anything but the notation. $\Box$

Edit: As richard remarked in the comments, part 2 of the lemma already suffices to answer my question: Take $n=1$, $X= [0,1]$. If $B \subseteq [0,1]$ is a Borel set with $\lambda(B) = 0$, then $\lambda(C) = 0$ for all Borel sets $C \subseteq B$. The lemma gives $\nu(C) = 0$ for all such $C$, so $|\nu|(B) =0$, since $D\nu$ exists everywhere by hypothesis (and is finite). This proves $\nu \ll \lambda$.

Theorem 8.21 in »Real Analysis« and its proof can be copied verbatim for the differentiation using balls, applying the lemma above instead of Lemma 8.20.

> **Theorem**: Let $\nu$ be a finite Radon measure on a cube $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $D\nu(x)$ (which is defined as $\overline{D}\nu(x)$ in case $\overline{D}\nu(x) = \underline{D}\nu(x) := \liminf \limits_{r \downarrow 0} {\frac{\nu(\overline{B}_r(x))}{\lambda(\overline{B}_r(x))}}$) exists for a. e. $x \in X$ and is integrable on $X$. Furthermore,
>   $$ \nu(E) = \int_E {D\nu}\, \mathcal{d}\lambda + \nu(E \cap B_\infty) + \nu(E \cap B_{-\infty})$$
>   for every Borel set $E \subseteq X$, where
>   $$ B_{\pm \infty} := \{x \in X \: | \: D\nu(x) = \pm\infty\}.$$

For my problem, choose $n=1$ and $X = [0,1]$. By hypothesis, $D\nu$ exists everywhere, so $B_{\pm \infty} = \emptyset$ and the theorem shows that $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Provided that $D\nu$ is finite everywhere, does part 2 of your lemma imply $\lambda(B)=0\Rightarrow |\nu|(B)=0$ and hence $\nu\ll\lambda$ immediately?

Comment: Another question: why is Vitali covering theorem applicable to $|\nu|$?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so. $\nu(B) = 0$ does not imply $|\nu|(B) = 0$. And I don't see a good connection between $D\nu$ and $\overline{D}|\nu|, \underline{D}|\nu|$. - And the Vitali-Besicovitch theorem only needs a positive Radon measure, which $|\nu|$ should be.

Comment: $\nu(B)=0$ does not imply $|\nu|(B)=0$, but your lemma implies that if $D\nu$ is finite everywhere, then $\lambda(B)=0\Rightarrow \lambda(C)=0,\forall C\subset B\Rightarrow \nu(C)=0,\forall C\subset B\Rightarrow |\nu|(B)=0$.

Comment: Ah, good point! It's still a nice theorem, so I'll leave it there as reference.

Comment: I did not learn about Vitali-Besicovitch covering theorem for Radon measures before, and maybe this is where I am stuck in considering your question. Now I have convinced myself of your answer. Thank you for your nice question and for helping me to learn this powerful theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, your comments and the bounty :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: There is a problem with the below argument: just because $f(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{2\epsilon} (F(x+\epsilon)-F(x-\epsilon))$ exists does not let us conclude that $F$ is differentiable (consider $F(x)=x^{1/3}$ at $x=0$).  So more work is needed.

Set $f(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{2\epsilon} \mu(]x+\epsilon, x-\epsilon[)$.  It is shown in Theorem 3.22 of Folland's *Real Analysis* that $f$ is the density of the absolutely continuous part of $\mu$; in particular, $f$ is integrable (with respect to Lebesgue measure).

If $F(x) = \mu([0,x))$, then $f = F'$ (**Edit: not yet proved**) (note that $F(x+\epsilon) - F(x-\epsilon) = \mu([x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon[)$ instead of $\mu(]x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon[)$, but $\mu$ has no atoms so they are actually equal).  Now Corollary 3.22 of *A First Course in Sobolev Spaces* by Giovanni Leoni ([free preview of relevant chapter](http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/gsm-105-prev.pdf)) says that any everywhere differentiable function with integrable derivative is absolutely continuous.   That means that $\mu$ itself is an absolutely continuous measure.

Comment: In general, $F'$ only exists Lebesgue almost everywhere, so how can you conclude that $F'=f$ everywhere?

Comment: @richard: I was thinking that $F'$ was precisely the limit that we are assuming to exist, but I've noted that this is not right.

Comment: It is too tricky for me to make use of the existence of the limit. Maybe as suggested by Thomas in the question, $\mu$ could be singular?